# Solve second order ODE by Kummer equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Hi I am trying to solve a second order ODE:

$xW(x)'' + (b + ax)W(x)' + cxW(x) = 0$

and after change of variable I have transformed into:

$yV(y)'' + (b - y)W(y)' - q = 0$

and the solution is $V(y) = C1*M(q, b, y) + C2*U(q, b y)$, where $y = gX$ and $W(x) = exp(nx)V(x)$

How can I get $W(x)$ from $V(y)$?

Thanks